# xcode 6.3.2 external build

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile

I'm trying to compile an existing c++ project, originally developed on linux with gcc. The only external library is GSL (GNU Scientific Library). I have created an external build tool project to use xcode's debugger, but I currently have two issues.

1) When I try to build in xcode it fails with the error `'gsl/gsl_matrix.h' file not found`. I have added `/usr/local/include` to the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` and confirmed that there is a `gsl` folder in that location, which contains all of the header files (installed with brew). However, if I type `make` in the CL then the project compiles without any errors, so I know there isn't an issue with my GSL, the makefile or the switch from gcc to clang.

I've looked at [Xcode 6.3.2 unable to build or run projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331302/xcode-6-3-2-unable-to-build-or-run-projects), and updated my xcode CL tools just in base, but I was already on the latest (2339).

2) While it would be nice to build from within xcode, it's not the end of the world if I have to build from the CL everytime. Once I've compiled everything I can run it from xcode, however, none of my breakpoints are hit. I have set the executable and the custom working directory in my debug scheme (as indicated by [Run C program in Xcode 4 using makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879697/run-c-program-in-xcode-4-using-makefile)). I've also looked through [Why aren't my breakpoints working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working) and haven't found anything that works.

I thought it might be operator error since I'm running the target with Product->Run, but I don't see any option to specifically start debug mode like intellij. I'm also able to pause the code and the debugger view comes up, but when I pause it just shows me the assembly instructions.

Comment: I'm having the same type of problem, can someone post the answer? I've tried turning it off and on again

Comment: I'm stuck on this too. I want to create a Makefile so I can compile this on a Mac and on a linux box. I added under 'Build Settings' `-I/usr/local/include/igraph` to OHTER_CFLAGS and `-L/usr/local/lib` to OTHER_LDFLAGS. Where do I add `-l graph` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've figured out both of my issues.

1) In the external build tool configuration I had to uncheck 'Pass build settings in environment'.

2) I'm a bit of an idiot here...I'd tried adding -g to my $(FLAGS) variable, but realized that was only applying to my executable. I modified the makefile to compile every single source file with -g and then breakpoints stopped on the source code (as opposed to disassembly).