# How to setup a C project in Xcode 6.3.* to build with a Makefile

Tags: c, xcode, command-line, makefile

I am adding a library `#include <igraph.h>` that I can access via

```
INCLUDES=-I/usr/local/include/igraph
LFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
LIBS=-ligraph
```

How do I create project on Mac's Xcode and setup the equivalent to `INCLUDES`, `LFLAGS`, and `LIBS` on Xcode 6.3.#?  I found a related SO [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879697), but it doesn't have all the info I need/look for.

The steps I took on Xcode:

1. New Project > OS X > Application > Command Line Tube
2. Entered a Product & Organization Name; Organizational identifier, Language=C
3. I picked a folder
4. On top left the project is selected, to the right I have Build Settings, Build Phases, Rules

But if I set the under the Build Settings > Compiled Sources :: Compiler Flags to `-I/usr/local/include/igraph -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph` I get the following warnings:

```
clang: warning: -ligraph: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
```

along with many errors that start with

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_igraph_community_infomap", referenced from:
> _infomap_weighted_test in ig_read_edgelist.o
> ```

I suspect *igraph* is a 64bit library, but will have to double check that.

But, again, what I am looking for is a way to generate a Makefile from the Xcode project that will allow me to compile the project on either system.